# Windows 10 File Explorer Crashes on Right-Click

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, right-click

This issue has been bothering me ever since my mom turned off my computer a few days ago and I turned it back on the next day to do some work. Right-clicking on any file or folder in Windows Explorer causes an hourglass icon to appear; the Explorer window inevitably goes Not Responding and when I click the X, the toolbar and icons in it disappear for a moment while the thing restarts. I've tried disabling all the third-party Context Menu extension things with that Shell Ex View program (they are currently all disabled), and uninstalling a few nonessential programs, but the problem persists. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen in safe mode?

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it (Onedrive, dropbox link). Here Are the steps to do this: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU I'll analyze it in the debugger

Comment: Windows' own hardware troubleshooting and SFC solved the problem for me, actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a few things.

- Try un/re-installing your third-party software.
- Look in your registry at `HKLM\*\shell` and `\shellex` and delete stragglers that may be left behind from the third-party software.  I would backup the registry before this, and maybe export the key, so you can perhaps get some of your old settings back after you get it working.
- Also try running `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command prompt.  You might even go through all the troubleshooting steps here: [System file check (SFC) Scan and Repair System Files & DISM to fix things SFC cannot](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93).